How is the Mathematica command FindGeometricTransformation related to the Kabsch agorithm?
I searched the internet for a Mathematica version of the Kabsch algorithm, using the search terms "Mathematica and Kabsch"  nothing came up in.  Looking through Mathematica documentation, I found the Mathematica command "FindGeometricTransformation".  It seems to be doing something similar and thus my question.
The Kabsch algorithm is an algorithm for registration of two sets of points in 2D or 3D. That is, it finds the optimal translation vector and rotation matrix that minimizes the root mean square deviation between two sets of points P and Q.

From the MA documentation, FindGeometricTransformation is more general because besides "lists of position coordinates" it can take "Wolfram Language graphics objects". Also, comparing with the description of the Kabsch algorithm given in Wikipedia, one can guess that the "Linear" method probably gives an implementation of the original algorithm. Does it answer your question?

Yes, thanks.  Does the "Linear" method give the optimal translation, too?

Let me give some illustration. We construct a set of points
ptsA = CirclePoints[{0., 0.}, 1., 5];
ptsB = CirclePoints[{2., 5.}, {2., Pi/3}, 5];

and find a transformation between them  (${\color{purple}A}\xrightarrow{f}{\color{red}B}$)
{e, f} = FindGeometricTransform[ptsB, ptsA, TransformationClass -> "Affine"]

$$ \left(
\begin{array}{cc|c}
 -0.813473 & -1.82709 & 2. \\
 1.82709 & -0.813473 & 5. \\\hline
 0. & 0. & 1. \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
As we see, this transform consists of translations, scaling and rotations.
This can be illustrated as
Graphics[{PointSize[0.1], Purple, Point@ptsA, Red, Point@ptsB, Blue, 
  PointSize[0.025], GeometricTransformation[Point@ptsA, f]}]


Kabsch algorithm
Alternatively, we can implement the Kabsch algorithm from scratch. The calculation will consist of 2 preliminary steps to determine translation and scaling followed by the actual Kabsch algorithm for rotations:

Translation ($B\rightarrow B_0$)
Uniform scaling ($B_0\rightarrow B_1$)
Rotation ($B_1\rightarrow B_2$)

Translation
t = TranslationTransform[Mean[ptsA] - Mean[ptsB]];
ptsB0 = t[ptsB];

Scaling
s = ScalingTransform[
  Norm[MeanDeviation[ptsA]]/Norm[MeanDeviation[ptsB0]]*{1, 1}];
ptsB1 = s[ptsB0];

Rotation
This is actually the original Kabsch algorithm
h = Transpose[ptsB1] . ptsA;
rm = MatrixPower[Transpose[h] . h, 1/2] . Inverse[h];
r = AffineTransform[rm];
ptsB2 = r[ptsB1];

Now we demonstrate that the whole sequence of transforms yields original set of points ${\color{red}B}\xrightarrow{translation} {\color{olive}B_0}\xrightarrow{scaling}{\color{brown}B_1}\xrightarrow{rotation}{\color{orange}B_2} = {\color{purple}A}$
Graphics[{PointSize[0.1], Purple, Point@ptsA, Red, Point@ptsB, 
  PointSize[0.05], Darker[Darker[Orange]], Point@ptsB0, 
  Darker[Orange], Point@ptsB1, Orange, Point@ptsB2}]



Very nice.  Many thanks. It would be helpful and informative if  the documentation mentions Kabsch.
